# Why is my 100GB hardrive showing as 1GB now

Tags: hard-drive

Yesterday, it was working correctly. But now this is happening.
Whenever i create a partition it wont work.

[image]

So when I try to create a **partition** on it
It replies with: error creating partition on /dev/sdb failed to meet partition size

I need help ASAP!

Comment: Fat16 might be problem, only for 4GBs.  Would try formatting to ext4 or something else you want.  Also make sure you don't have a USB or SD card connected(they might be listed as sdb now).  sb(x) can change at boot.

Answer (score 3):

FAT16 is a file system introduced in **1984** for DOS.

The max partition size using FAT16 (32KiB clusters) is 2GB.  Roughly the size of your current 1.81GiB partition.

Use Gparted or Disks to format the drive with a modern file system.

Comment: Just make sure you are working on right drive/partition.  Double check and check again.  Formatting wrong drive is no fun.  Quite sure you have an USB/SD now listed as sdb since yesterday.

Comment: hello so i tried but
https://pastebin.com/Be3Cfr01